# Delete all documents returned in a find().limit()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using `db.collection.find({}, {'_id': False}).limit(2000)` to get the documents from a collection. This documents are sent to a Facebook API, after the API return success this documents need to be deleted from the collection.

**My main doubt is:**

- Is there a way to I delete all this 2000 documents withou using a for
  loop? I know that `collection.find` returns a cursor, is there a way
  to use this cursor in a `delete_many`?

The structure of my document is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61608068887f1a0e2162d94b"),
    "event_time" : "1632582893",
    "value" : "549.9000",
    "contents" : [ 
        {
            "product_id" : "1-1",
            "quantity" : "1.000000",
            "value" : "10"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: db.collection.remove({_id: 
    { $in: db.collection.find().limit(2000).map(a => a._id) }
})

Comment: in delete_many again you have to get either all ids upto 2000 using loop .. or if any key which helps in identifying 2000 records

Comment: Thanks @adarsh ! I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: @adarsh Since I'm using pymongo i'll need to develop a pipeline to run this `map`?

Comment: You can use project stage to return only an array of `_ids`.

Comment: you can use list comprehension type approach instead of map or you can store the data in var then pass the variable there ... or use Projection {_id: 1} as mentioned by @J.F. but in this case your array will be like [{_id:1},{_id:2}]

Comment: If still you face the problem then I will add a solution in the morning.

Comment: How are the documents sent to the Facebook API?  You may be able to push the _id of the document into an array as you prepare/send those API calls, and then pass that array to deleteMany upon success.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. Its holiday in my country. I'm going to try all sugestions tomorrow, and if I still face the issue I'll reply here again! Thanks again @adarsh.

Comment: @Joe they are sent using pagination, If the api returns `Success[200]`, the documents can be deleted. I dont send the `_id` to the API

Comment: @J.F. I'll try this tomorrow too!

Comment: @adarsh When I try to remove by ID using a list MongoDB does not delete data: `db.Facebook.find({}, {'_id': 1}).limit(5)` returns `_id : ObjectID(...)`. When I try to remove using this list, like `db.Facebook.delete_many( {'_id': {'$in': (list(remove_dados))}})` the document is not removed since `$in` needs only the `ObjectID(...)` and not `_id: ObjectID(...)`. Any suggestion to solve this? I've tried to convert the list to a string and replace `'_id : ` with blank space, but no success (and I think it's not the best way to do this...)

Comment: @OdiumPura  sry i was totally busy with product release ... I'm glad you found the solution yourself. (So I voted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, based on the comments of @adarsh and @J.F I've used the following code:

```
rm = [x['_id'] for x in MongoDB(mongo).db.get_collection("DataToSend").find({}, {'_id' : 1}).limit(2000)

MongoDB(mongo).db.get_collection("DataToSend").delete_many({'_id' : { '$in' : list(rm)}})
```